# how to use c++ to create webrtc native custom audio source? (M110)

Tags: c++, webrtc

I have been looking for information on the Internet for a long time, most of which are about using AuidoDeviceModule to implement custom audio input. After I tried it, I found that there is a problem, the client cannot receive any audio track, and the OnTrack in Observer will only exist the video track.

```cpp
class AudioCaptureModule 
    : public webrtc::AudioDeviceModule
    , public rtc::RefCountInterface
{
// ...
}

auto adm = new rtc::RefCountedObject<AudioCaptureModule>();
auto pc_factory = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        std::move(adm),
        webrtc::CreateBuiltinAudioEncoderFactory(),
        webrtc::CreateBuiltinAudioDecoderFactory(),
        webrtc::CreateBuiltinVideoEncoderFactory(),
        webrtc::CreateBuiltinVideoDecoderFactory(),
        nullptr,
        nullptr);
```

I also found the AudioSourceInterface class, but I don’t know if it can be implemented, because it seems to be the way of the version (such as M79) a long time ago, and the version I am using now is M110 (the latest stable version), is there any latest stable version A way to implement a custom audio input and make receiving remote audio tracks work?

```cpp
class CustomAudioSource : public rtc::RefCountedObject<webrtc::AudioSourceInterface> {
public:
  explicit CustomAudioSource(int sample_rate_hz) : sample_rate_hz_(sample_rate_hz) {}
  
  void AddSink(AudioTrackSinkInterface* sink) override {
    sinks_.push_back(sink);
  }

  void RemoveSink(AudioTrackSinkInterface* sink) override {
    auto it = std::find(sinks_.begin(), sinks_.end(), sink);
    if (it != sinks_.end()) {
      sinks_.erase(it);
    }
  }

  void GenerateAudio(int16_t* audio_data, int sample_rate_hz, size_t num_channels, size_t num_samples) {
    for (auto sink : sinks_) {
      sink->OnData(audio_data, num_samples, sample_rate_hz, num_channels);
    }
  }

private:
  int sample_rate_hz_;
  std::vector<AudioTrackSinkInterface*> sinks_;
};

rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::PeerConnectionFactoryInterface> peer_connection_factory =
    webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory();

webrtc::PeerConnectionInterface::RTCConfiguration config;
rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::PeerConnectionInterface> peer_connection =
    peer_connection_factory->CreatePeerConnection(config, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

auto audio_device_module = webrtc::AudioDeviceModule::Create(0, webrtc::AudioDeviceModule::kPlatformDefaultAudio);
auto audio_source = std::make_unique<MyCustomAudioSource2>();
auto audio_track = peer_connection_factory->CreateAudioTrack("audio_track", audio_device_module->CreateAudioSource(std::move(audio_source)));

peer_connection->AddTrack(audio_track, {"stream"});
```

Answer (score -1):

The implementation of `ADM` is correct, this implementation refers to the `WebrtcAudioModule` in chromium.

```cpp
//
//  audio_capture_module.h
//  rtc
//
//  Created by Mr.Panda on 2023/2/22.
//

#ifndef audio_capture_module_h
#define audio_capture_module_h
#pragma once

#include "modules/audio_device/include/audio_device.h"
#include "modules/audio_mixer/audio_mixer_impl.h"
#include "api/peer_connection_interface.h"

class AudioCaptureModule
: public webrtc::AudioDeviceModule
{
public:
    static rtc::scoped_refptr<AudioCaptureModule> Create();
    int32_t ActiveAudioLayer(AudioLayer* audioLayer) const;
    int32_t RegisterAudioCallback(webrtc::AudioTransport* audio_callback);
    
    // Only supported on iOS.
#ifdef WEBRTC_IOS
    int GetPlayoutAudioParameters(webrtc::AudioParameters* params) const;
    int GetRecordAudioParameters(webrtc::AudioParameters* params) const;
#endif  // WEBRTC_IOS
    
    // Main initialization and termination
    int32_t Init();
    int32_t Terminate();
    bool Initialized() const;
    
    // Device enumeration
    int16_t PlayoutDevices();
    int16_t RecordingDevices();
    int32_t PlayoutDeviceName(uint16_t index,
                              char name[webrtc::kAdmMaxDeviceNameSize],
                              char guid[webrtc::kAdmMaxGuidSize]);
    int32_t RecordingDeviceName(uint16_t index,
                                char name[webrtc::kAdmMaxDeviceNameSize],
                                char guid[webrtc::kAdmMaxGuidSize]);
    
    // Device selection
    int32_t SetPlayoutDevice(uint16_t index);
    int32_t SetPlayoutDevice(WindowsDeviceType device);
    int32_t SetRecordingDevice(uint16_t index);
    int32_t SetRecordingDevice(WindowsDeviceType device);
    
    // Audio transport initialization
    int32_t PlayoutIsAvailable(bool* available);
    int32_t InitPlayout();
    bool PlayoutIsInitialized() const;
    int32_t RecordingIsAvailable(bool* available);
    int32_t InitRecording();
    bool RecordingIsInitialized() const;
    
    // Audio transport control
    int32_t StartPlayout();
    int32_t StopPlayout();
    
    // True when audio is being pulled by the instance.
    bool Playing() const;
    int32_t StartRecording();
    int32_t StopRecording();
    bool Recording() const;
    
    // Audio mixer initialization
    int32_t InitSpeaker();
    bool SpeakerIsInitialized() const;
    int32_t InitMicrophone();
    bool MicrophoneIsInitialized() const;
    
    // Speaker volume controls
    int32_t SpeakerVolumeIsAvailable(bool* available);
    int32_t SetSpeakerVolume(uint32_t volume);
    int32_t SpeakerVolume(uint32_t* volume) const;
    int32_t MaxSpeakerVolume(uint32_t* maxVolume) const;
    int32_t MinSpeakerVolume(uint32_t* minVolume) const;
    
    // Microphone volume controls
    int32_t MicrophoneVolumeIsAvailable(bool* available);
    int32_t SetMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t volume);
    int32_t MicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* volume) const;
    int32_t MaxMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* max_volume) const;
    int32_t MinMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* min_volume) const;
    
    // Speaker mute control
    int32_t SpeakerMuteIsAvailable(bool* available);
    int32_t SetSpeakerMute(bool enable);
    int32_t SpeakerMute(bool* enabled) const;
    
    // Microphone mute control
    int32_t MicrophoneMuteIsAvailable(bool* available);
    int32_t SetMicrophoneMute(bool enable);
    int32_t MicrophoneMute(bool* enabled) const;
    
    // Stereo support
    int32_t StereoPlayoutIsAvailable(bool* available) const;
    int32_t SetStereoPlayout(bool enable);
    int32_t StereoPlayout(bool* enabled) const;
    int32_t StereoRecordingIsAvailable(bool* available) const;
    int32_t SetStereoRecording(bool enable);
    int32_t StereoRecording(bool* enabled) const;
    
    // Playout delay
    int32_t PlayoutDelay(uint16_t* delay_ms) const;
    bool BuiltInAECIsAvailable() const;
    bool BuiltInAGCIsAvailable() const;
    bool BuiltInNSIsAvailable() const;
    
    // Enables the built-in audio effects. Only supported on Android.
    int32_t EnableBuiltInAEC(bool enable);
    int32_t EnableBuiltInAGC(bool enable);
    int32_t EnableBuiltInNS(bool enable);
private:
    bool Initialize();
    
    webrtc::AudioTransport* _audio_transport = NULL;
    bool _initialized;
    bool _playing;
};


#endif /* audio_capture_module_h */
```

```cpp
//
//  audio_capture_module.cpp
//  rtc
//
//  Created by Mr.Panda on 2023/2/22.
//

#include "audio_capture_module.h"

rtc::scoped_refptr<AudioCaptureModule> AudioCaptureModule::Create()
{
    return rtc::make_ref_counted<AudioCaptureModule>();
}


int32_t AudioCaptureModule::ActiveAudioLayer(AudioLayer* audio_layer) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::RegisterAudioCallback(
                                                  webrtc::AudioTransport* audio_transport)
{
    _audio_transport = audio_transport;
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::Init()
{
    _initialized = true;
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::Terminate()
{
    _initialized = false;
    return 0;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::Initialized() const
{
    return _initialized;
}

int16_t AudioCaptureModule::PlayoutDevices()
{
    return 0;
}

int16_t AudioCaptureModule::RecordingDevices()
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::PlayoutDeviceName(
                                              uint16_t index,
                                              char name[webrtc::kAdmMaxDeviceNameSize],
                                              char guid[webrtc::kAdmMaxGuidSize])
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::RecordingDeviceName(
                                                uint16_t index,
                                                char name[webrtc::kAdmMaxDeviceNameSize],
                                                char guid[webrtc::kAdmMaxGuidSize])
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetPlayoutDevice(uint16_t index)
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetPlayoutDevice(WindowsDeviceType device)
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetRecordingDevice(uint16_t index)
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetRecordingDevice(WindowsDeviceType device)
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::PlayoutIsAvailable(bool* available)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::InitPlayout()
{
    return 0;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::PlayoutIsInitialized() const
{
    return _initialized;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::RecordingIsAvailable(bool* available)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::InitRecording()
{
    return 0;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::RecordingIsInitialized() const
{
    return false;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::StartPlayout()
{
    _playing = true;
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::StopPlayout()
{
    _playing = false;
    return 0;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::Playing() const
{
    return _playing;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::StartRecording()
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::StopRecording()
{
    return 0;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::Recording() const
{
    return false;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::InitSpeaker()
{
    return 0;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::SpeakerIsInitialized() const
{
    return false;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::InitMicrophone()
{
    return 0;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::MicrophoneIsInitialized() const
{
    return false;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SpeakerVolumeIsAvailable(bool* available)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetSpeakerVolume(uint32_t volume)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SpeakerVolume(uint32_t* volume) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::MaxSpeakerVolume(uint32_t* max_volume) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::MinSpeakerVolume(uint32_t* min_volume) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::MicrophoneVolumeIsAvailable(bool* available)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t volume)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::MicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* volume) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::MaxMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* max_volume) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::MinMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* min_volume) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SpeakerMuteIsAvailable(bool* available)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetSpeakerMute(bool enable)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SpeakerMute(bool* enabled) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::MicrophoneMuteIsAvailable(bool* available)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetMicrophoneMute(bool enable)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::MicrophoneMute(bool* enabled) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::StereoPlayoutIsAvailable(bool* available) const
{
    *available = true;
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetStereoPlayout(bool enable)
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::StereoPlayout(bool* enabled) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::StereoRecordingIsAvailable(bool* available) const
{
    *available = false;
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::SetStereoRecording(bool enable)
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::StereoRecording(bool* enabled) const
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::PlayoutDelay(uint16_t* delay_ms) const
{
    *delay_ms = 0;
    return 0;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::BuiltInAECIsAvailable() const
{
    return false;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::BuiltInAGCIsAvailable() const
{
    return false;
}

bool AudioCaptureModule::BuiltInNSIsAvailable() const
{
    return false;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::EnableBuiltInAEC(bool enable)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::EnableBuiltInAGC(bool enable)
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t AudioCaptureModule::EnableBuiltInNS(bool enable)
{
    return -1;
}

#if defined(WEBRTC_IOS)
int AudioCaptureModule::GetPlayoutAudioParameters(
                                                  webrtc::AudioParameters* params) const
{
    return -1;
}

int AudioCaptureModule::GetRecordAudioParameters(
                                                 webrtc::AudioParameters* params) const
{
    return -1;
}
#endif  // WEBRTC_IOS
```

Comment: This solution may be useful but it's just code with no explanation. Answers should give a brief explanation of what the code did and how you solved the issue,